# How to make a union of 2 sets in scheme

Tags: set, scheme, racket

```
(define (element-of-set x lst1)
 (cond ((null? lst1) '())
    ((equal? x (car lst1)) (cons (car lst1) (element-of-set x (cdr lst1))))
    (else
     (element-of-set x (cdr lst1)))))

(define (helper set1 set2) (append set1 set2))

(define (union-set set1 set2)
(cond ((null? set1) '())
    ((> (length (element-of-set (car set1) (helper set1 set2))) 1) (cons (car set1) (union-set (cdr set1) (cdr set2))))
    ((> (length (element-of-set (car set2) (helper set1 set2))) 1) (cons (car set2) (union-set (cdr set1) (cdr set2))))
    (else
     (append (helper set1 set2) (union-set (cdr set1) (cdr set2))))))
```

This code is suppose to find the union of 2 sets. I tried to put the two sets together and then take out any repeats but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/set)

(define (union-set set1 set2)
  (set-union set1 set2))

(union-set '(1 2 3) '(4 3 2))
=> '(4 1 2 3)
```

FYI, `set` is a built-in data type in Racket, so it's easy to write a set union - just call the existing procedure! Anyway, if you want to roll your own version it's also easy, and simpler than your current implementation:

```
(define (element-of-set x lst1)
  (cond ((null? lst1) #f)
        ((equal? x (car lst1)) #t)
        (else (element-of-set x (cdr lst1)))))

(define (union-set set1 set2)
  (cond ((null? set1) set2)
        ((element-of-set (car set1) set2)
         (union-set (cdr set1) set2))
        (else
         (cons (car set1) (union-set (cdr set1) set2)))))
```

Comment: Require is not defined in R5RS.

Comment: This is not R5RS, this is Racket (see the first line). Anyway, I updated my answer with a solution by hand. By all means, avoid using `append` and `length` when building an output list, there are far better ways to write a solution.

Comment: When I input (union-set '(1 2 3) '(2 1 5 6)), it gives me (2 1 5 6). However, 3 should also be in the output.

Comment: @sara for me the above code returns correctly: `'(3 2 1 5 6)` , so there must be an error on your side, copy-paste the code again (both procedures!), make sure that you're displaying it correctly, and try again. In fact, I'm pretty sure that you forgot to copy my version of `element-of-set`, because yours was incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I'd do it in Common Lisp if it didn't include functions for set operations.

```
(defun set-union (set1 set2)
  (remove-duplicates (append set1 set2)))
```

I'll write one in Scheme.